# Get values passed to constructor of mock object

Tags: python, python-3.x, mocking

Assuming this scenario:

```
import random
import string

class objectToMock:

    Arg1:list = []
    Arg2:list = None

    def __init__(self, arg1:list, arg2:str):
        self.Arg1 = arg1
        self.Arg2 = arg2
        return

def functionToTest():
    #Get list of random numbers.
    listArg = []
    for x in range(0,5):
         listArg.append(random.randint(1,1000))

    #Get a random string
    stringArg = \
        ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5))


    return objectToMock(listArg, stringArg)
```

If i want to test the `functionToTest` function, how do i mock `objectToMock` so that i can get the values passed to `objectToMock`'s construnctor?

This is where i've got so far:

```
import unittest.mock
import #Module with my test objects

def Test_functionToTest
    with mock(objectToMock) as mock_objectToMock:
        result = functionToTest()
```

i'm not sure how to get the values passed to mock_objectToMock.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `call_args_list` from your mock object and unpack it as a `tuple`. Here's how:

```
import random
import string

class ObjectToMock(object):
    arg1:list = []
    arg2:list = None
    def __init__(self, arg1:list, arg2:str):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        return

def function_to_test():
    #Get list of random numbers.
    list_arg = []
    for x in range(0,5):
         list_arg.append(random.randint(1,1000))
    #Get a random string
    string_arg = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5))
    return ObjectToMock(list_arg, string_arg)

from unittest.mock import patch

def test_function_to_test():
    with patch('__main__.ObjectToMock') as mock_object_to_mock:
        result = function_to_test()
        for call_obj in mock_object_to_mock.call_args_list:
            args, kwargs = call_obj  # Unpack the call function as a tuple
            print('Here are my args: {}, kwargs: {}'.format(args, kwargs))
```

Note that I ran it all in one script so the object I'm patching is in `__main__`. Yours would be in whatever module your class lives in. Also note that I changed all the camel casing/snake casing mixing. You should try to adhere to python style guides as it makes reading/maintaining your code easier for you and others.